# Weighted SUMIF-like query in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with a column of dates, a second column with a duration of an event on that date, and a third column with separate, unrelated dates, as follows,

```
        A            B           C
1   date         duration    eval_date
2   2023-01-01   5           2022-08-04
3   2023-01-01   7           2021-23-07
4   2023-05-02   9           2023-11-11
5                            2024-01-07
```

On each `eval_date`, I want to do an exponentially weighted sum of all durations in the past. A bit like this:

```
SUMIF($A$2:$A$4, "<" & C2, $B$2:$B$4*EXP(-(C2-$A$2:$A$4) )
```

Only problem: it's not allowed to do any calculations in the SUMIF `[sum_range]` argument. So instead I looked at the `REDUCE` function. I tried something as follows, which only sums the weight factors:

```
REDUCE(0,$A$2:$A$4,LAMBDA(a,b,a+IF(b<C2,EXP(-(C2-b)),0)))
```

However, I have no way to somehow multiply the exponential with the duration. Something like a hypothetical function `REDUCE([initial_value],array1,array2,lambda(accumulator,value1,value2))`. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `SUMPRODUCT` does allow calculations inside its arguments. So we get

```
SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$4<C2)*$B$2:$B$4*EXP($A$2:$A$4-C2))
```

Went down the wrong rabbit hole apparently.